# Showing error " Database read only "

Tags: c#-4.0

I have make Setup in visual studio 2010 in C# windows application and it is perfect. There is no any problem in installation but when the operation performed there is an error " The database is read only".
There is no any problem is connection and connection string. Please Give me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure database files for example mdf file in MSSQL server is writeable. You can also try following query to get info about your database.

```
use master
select name, status from sysdatabases
```